# Signing a text file using a pfx file in java

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, private-key

I'm very new to java cryptography. I'm trying to use a .pfx file that contains a public key, it's private key and a digital certificate to sign a text file. I have been able to access the private key and certificates by loading the .pfx file to the java key store. I want to sign the data using the private key in the .pfx file and then append the digital certificate along with it.

```
        Certificate[] certificatechain = null;
    PrivateKey signerkey = null;
    Certificate certificate = null;
    PrivateKey pvtkey = null;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\21617\\Desktop\\Uttara Pers\\uttararead.txt"); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    Enumeration<String> aliasList;
    String alias;
    String pfxPath = "D:\\Document Signer\\Test-Class3DocumentSigner2014\\Class 3 Docsigntest.pfx", certPassword = "password";
    File securityFileKeyPair = new File(pfxPath);
    InputStream cerFileStream = new FileInputStream(securityFileKeyPair);
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
    keyStore.load(cerFileStream, certPassword.toCharArray());
    aliasList = keyStore.aliases();
    while (aliasList.hasMoreElements()) {
        alias = aliasList.nextElement();
    KeyStore.ProtectionParameter entryPassword = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(certPassword.toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, entryPassword);
    pvtkey = privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
    System.out.println("Private key is:" +pvtkey);
    certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
    signerkey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, certPassword.toCharArray());
    certificatechain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
    }
```

This is where I'm and want to be able to create a digital signature using the contents loaded from the respective .pfx file.
I want to be able to do the same using the private key and certificate I get from the .pfx file.

```
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\21617\\Desktop\\Uttara Pers\\uttararead.txt"); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair pair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privKey = pair.getPrivate();
    Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    sign.initSign(privKey);
    byte[] bytes = "br".getBytes();
    sign.update(bytes);
    byte[] signature = sign.sign();
    String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("signature".getBytes("utf-8"));
    System.out.println("Digital signature of the file: "+base64encodedString);
```

This code ^ is what I've written to generate a raw signature. The sign object here is used to call and use the other things necessary for signing here. What object would I have to create for my problem which would be an equivalent of the sign object in this code.

I've been stuck at this point for quite sometime. Kindly point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid you're doing yourself no favours by posting images of code. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly edit your question and add a minimal but full running example of your most recent code. Please do not post images with your code as the people are trying to help you don't want to type in your code to check what the problem is, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Thank you. I have added now added my code for reference

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had all functions available to retrieve the RSA private key and certificate out of the pfx-file
(it's a PKCS12 keystore).

I combined your two parts of code to a full running example. For verification there are two options available:

- option 1: verifiy the signature with a public key (get the key with "certificate.getPublicKey()"
- option 2: verify the signature with a certifcation

Please note that the code does not have any exception handling. As well the choosen signature algorithm is determistic -
there are better signature algorithms available.

This is the output of the code:

```
RSA signature with PFX file
Private key is:SunRsaSign RSA private CRT key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 20745681504295693338677598037425633054507196204877617419598634508842069647867075532992638954699743584297973637862386311040528331616364569181369404804703632552254162535558790075462853537556395029598445155559243819343605229254467273028470726088176140177653714749221474473368350858555614299113027040172126183258283581653894576374347297382002730107326970070574009149026236812216305173786045476886384540029067882067718179791112458402510855090943584133554670768670628348813208331767176300365697917644826900592782794277988966122352778692005555958605707879606264701810912582675085618198935971375640570974842583935544764079181
  private exponent: 7885872371866492400523922704859047113140413382606942721776113994907817554475557100232122642774005709324978550535236092293538639199641029455823040610567723486606889193674421751986368117667957229921364507305672856973738399242981654724587068805539527352575023907603420542297516770501204867777037850752521590511057404116851028618930420914266791736061751403423747879412785083579614624025989162418565474432973854813362120531945085369119091233141833194635650026465869705622286632392621017540662631025145908079890706307098133032113785352742799568343731292342294933488080974275377487016175861831017175736029834746462206620673
certificate is: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=Test@Test.com, CN=Test, OU=Test, O=Test, L=Test, ST=Test, C=DE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 20745681504295693338677598037425633054507196204877617419598634508842069647867075532992638954699743584297973637862386311040528331616364569181369404804703632552254162535558790075462853537556395029598445155559243819343605229254467273028470726088176140177653714749221474473368350858555614299113027040172126183258283581653894576374347297382002730107326970070574009149026236812216305173786045476886384540029067882067718179791112458402510855090943584133554670768670628348813208331767176300365697917644826900592782794277988966122352778692005555958605707879606264701810912582675085618198935971375640570974842583935544764079181
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Jul 28 18:06:11 CEST 2021,
               To: Sat Jul 26 18:06:11 CEST 2031]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=Test@Test.com, CN=Test, OU=Test, O=Test, L=Test, ST=Test, C=DE
  SerialNumber: [    7512a982 8d398731 a0e27f4d 4b0e2be2 45b2041c]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 83 B4 2A 8D 55 76 07 5F   DF 2C 62 9F DC 76 69 55  ..*.Uv._.,b..viU
0010: 56 64 EE C5                                        Vd..
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 83 B4 2A 8D 55 76 07 5F   DF 2C 62 9F DC 76 69 55  ..*.Uv._.,b..viU
0010: 56 64 EE C5                                        Vd..
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 3C 69 CD 56 0B BF 4E 0E   B3 8C B4 D6 C3 AB D7 C4  <i.V..N.........
...
00F0: E1 81 C5 D8 F5 90 D4 09   CA ED 12 76 8C 12 F7 A3  ...........v....

]
Digital signature of the file: LiJEB4cjSNxmcibSg5V2dgFwydvyQ4xaCJswkIHZtCPkCu17jMZszFkv6kFOhXaPLuQ49vnghXXqdXzuuX5r5y3aNyoSZMjNtk+p9cG1t+eX9FrDMkUQ7Krrl6+K/Z5vMpKlfdxC6eZx6D4qlng1isHAlVSu9yzpgE3Wxtyl7I6v5Y7kFsx+LcAztoGVpZnH8Ta96HoG+B6NhmwfsgZ2GvrN9c5jA/S3bqEb4tFplkhFAwCWWEL1PvCTMREv8Y/Y7Muew9c35hAJKdweo/CCudrSflciEUUR1Emi+Z3KzDBMNgGZQmxBnZa4X88E5HJZdHl5HHnPeB6vStQLvtyg2g==
signatureVerified: true
```

Here is the full code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class TestRsaSignatureWithPfxFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableEntryException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        System.out.println("RSA signature with PFX file");

        Certificate certificate = null;
        PrivateKey pvtkey = null;

        // load key from pfx keystore
        Enumeration<String> aliasList;
        String alias;
        String pfxPath = "pfxCertificate.pfx", certPassword = "password";
        File securityFileKeyPair = new File(pfxPath);
        InputStream cerFileStream = new FileInputStream(securityFileKeyPair);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(cerFileStream, certPassword.toCharArray());
        aliasList = keyStore.aliases();
        while (aliasList.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = aliasList.nextElement();
            KeyStore.ProtectionParameter entryPassword = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(certPassword.toCharArray());
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, entryPassword);
            pvtkey = privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
            System.out.println("Private key is:" + pvtkey);
            certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
            System.out.println("certificate is: " + certificate);

            // sign
            PrivateKey privKey = pvtkey;
            Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            sign.initSign(privKey);
            byte[] bytes = "some testdata to sign".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            sign.update(bytes);
            byte[] signature = sign.sign();
            String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
            System.out.println("Digital signature of the file: " + base64encodedString);

            // verify
            PublicKey pubKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
            Signature verify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            // verification with the public key inside certificate
            verify.initVerify(pubKey);
            // verification with the certificate itself
            //verify.initVerify(certificate);
            verify.update(bytes);
            boolean signatureVerified = verify.verify(signature);
            System.out.println("signatureVerified: " + signatureVerified);
        }
    }
}
```